# Add logical value inside new column according to 'NA' values

Tags: r

Let's say I have this data:

```
name <- c("Name1","Name2","Name3","Name4",NA)
state <- c("State1","State2","State3","State4","State5")
id <- c("id1",NA,NA,"id4","id5")
size <- c(NA,"size2",NA,"size4",NA)
```

and then i create this `df`

```
df <- data.frame(name,state,id,size)

> df
   name  state  id  size
1 Name1 State1 id1  NA    
2 Name2 State2 NA   size2
3 Name3 State3 NA   NA    
4 Name4 State4 id4  size4
5 NA    State5 id5  NA
```

And the `class` of the columns is defined in a vector like this:

```
vars <- c("name","state","id","size")
type <- c("A","A","B","C")

class <- data.frame(vars,type)

> class
   vars type
1  name    A
2 state    A
3    id    B
4  size    C
```

What i want to do is create another column, named with the `type`, so i can get and logical output value: if at least one of the same `type` is not NA, it should return true inside them, just like this:

```
   name  state  id  size  A     B      C
 1 Name1 State1 id1 NA    TRUE  TRUE   FALSE
 2 Name2 State2 NA  size2 TRUE  FALSE  TRUE
 3 Name3 State3 NA  NA    TRUE  FALSE  FALSE
 4 Name4 State4 id4 size4 TRUE  TRUE   TRUE
 5 NA    State5 id5 NA    TRUE  TRUE   FALSE
```

How could i work on it to get something like the desired output?

Comment: For e.g. in your 'size' column input it is `""` for the first observation and `""` for the last

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `split` the 'vars' column by the 'type' in the 'class' dataset (`class`is a function name), loop through the `list`, subset the 'df' columns from the 'vars', convert it to a logical `matrix` by checking it is not equal to a blank, get the `rowSums` and create a logical `vector` by comparing it with the number of columns of the dataset i.e. we are checking the number of TRUE values are equal to the number of columns

```
cbind(df, sapply(split(as.character(class$vars), class$type),
             function(x) rowSums(df[x] != "") == ncol(df[x])))
#   name  state  id  size     A     B     C
#1 Name1 State1 id1        TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#2 Name2 State2     size2  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
#3 Name3 State3            TRUE FALSE FALSE
#4 Name4 State4 id4 size4  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#5       State5 id5       FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

---

Another option without using the `split` would be loop through the 'unique` elements of the 'type' column in 'class' and then do the subsetting

```
library(tidyverse)
class %>%
    pull(type) %>%
    unique %>% 
    map(~ class %>%
              filter(type == .x) %>% 
              pull(vars) %>% 
              as.character %>% 
              select(df, .) %>%
               `!=`("") %>%
              as_tibble %>%
              reduce(`&`)) %>%
    bind_cols(df, .)
```

#### Update

Based on the updated dataset in the OP's post with `NA` elements, we replace the `df[x] != ""` to `!is.na(df[x])`

```
cbind(df, sapply(split(as.character(class$vars), class$type),
         function(x) rowSums(!is.na(df[x])) >0))
#   name  state   id  size    A     B     C
#1 Name1 State1  id1  <NA> TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#2 Name2 State2 <NA> size2 TRUE FALSE  TRUE
#3 Name3 State3 <NA>  <NA> TRUE FALSE FALSE
#4 Name4 State4  id4 size4 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#5  <NA> State5  id5  <NA> TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Hi there! Thank you for the answer, but still wouldn't do it, becase the 5th line should return FALSE, TRUE and TRUE !

Because it depends on two variables that has the same class

Comment: @LuccaRamalho  Please check your input dataset.  Your values are not matching with the expected

Comment: thank you, @akrun ! I've fixed it now. Hope it's clear now =)

Comment: @LuccaRamalho  Fixed the issue

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm trying with another huge dataset and it gave me an error message... but i'll try to figure it out what happened.. i couldn't get why you had to use the "split" function

Comment: @LuccaRamalho  You can do this in many ways.  The `split` will split the values of 'vars' based on the unique values of 'type'.  Without knowing the error, it is difficult to give answer

Comment: is there a way to do it like: newdf <- cbind(df, A = df$state=="" | df$id=="")

but instead of typing each of the $ parameters i'd return a list so it would be like 
newdf <- cbind(df, A = ListOfTypeA="")

thanks a lot in advance (:

Comment: @LuccaRamalho  That is exactly the code is doing automatically except that you have to split based on the values of 'class'

Comment: Also, the `split` method be very fast compared to doing subsets.  As you didn't provide the exact error, it is unclear where you are stuck

Comment: hmm, got it... i'll have to go now but i'll solve it and return it here!
Thank you so veru much again.

Comment: is there a way to adapt the code to find "NA" values? I think that's the problem with my code.

Comment: @LuccaRamalho  Do you have blanks `""` or `NA` ?

Comment: Please update your post with a representative example.

Comment: If it is `NA`, instead of `df != ""` it should be `!is.na(df)`

Comment: i'm really sorry for the long comment post, but is there a way to return true if there is at least one field that is not NA?

Comment: @LuccaRamalho  Use `any` i.e. wrap with `any` on the `!is.na`

Comment: you're my hero! Thank's a lot for the useful help and patience. =)

Comment: @LuccaRamalho  thank you  I updated my previous comment.  Without updating your post and expected output, it is hard to comment what you really want

Comment: i've updated the question... if you want to update the answer too you're welcome!